# Adaptive seats because of Total Knee Replacement

Tags: saddle, adaptive

After TKR (total knee replacement) have a difficult time in foot placement on pedal, my right foot falls in middle due to range of motion? Any ideas or suggestions?

I thought if I found a seat that sat back, it would allow for right foot to hit at ball!

Comment: Could you use a longer crank arm on that side or maybe a larger than normal platform pedal?

Comment: @mikes - It would be a *shorter* crank arm on the side of the bad knee.

Comment: They're is no need to strike the pedal with the ball of your foot. Your mud foot is as good a position as any. It reduces strain on lower leg muscles, which may be an advantage to cycling endurance.

Comment: We can make suggestions, but a proper diagnosis needs a physiologically-trained sports advisor to measure you and give you a bike-fit.

Comment: An experienced bike fitter with medical knowledge could help here. Ask your physiotherapist.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a company called Rans

http://www.ransbikes.com/

that makes bikes that they call crank forward.  You might say it’s halfway between a recumbent and a conventional bike.

They cost more than I would be inclined to pay, but your seat will be back.

Comment: "semi-recumbent" is another name for crank-forward style.